# Call to a member function on a non-object when using MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I've been working on a relatively simple project, and to make it even easier I decided to use [this](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) PHP class to make database connections easier. However, I've come into a few issues with it.

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
require_once('lib/db.php');

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$db = new MysqliDb('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'url_shortener');

$app->get('/u/:url', function ($url) {
    $urls = $db
        ->where('short', $url)
        ->get('urls');
    //require('views/u.php');
    print_r($urls);
});
```

When I navigate to /u/1 I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in [my site index]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$db` variable isn't available inside the anonymous function you've declared. You're assuming it to be an object, but since it's not defined, it's `NULL` (inside the function). With closures, to access variables that are outside of the scope of the function, you can  grant permission to the function using the [`use`](http://php.net/use) keyword.

```
$app->get('/u/:url', function ($url) use ($db) { ... }
```

Now `$db` is available inside the function scope and you can use it however you wish.

Comment: Awesome, just what I wanted.

Comment: @BenedictLewis: Glad to have been of help. Cheers! :)

Comment: One more quick question, now that it works it outputs `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [short] => 1 [long] => [ "http://www.getbootstrap.com", "http://www.reddit.com", "http://www.bbc.com/news", "http://www.google.com" ] ) )`. What I am now trying to do is just print out the URLs under 'long'. I have tried `print_r($urls['long'])` and `print_r($urls->long)` but it doesn't work. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: @BenedictLewis: `echo $urls[0]['long'];` should do it. Also, you can get a formatted output of the array if you wrap `print_r()` in `<pre>` tags, like so: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($urls, true) . '</pre>';`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import $db within your Closure:

```
$app->get('/u/:url', function ($url) use ($db) { ... }
```